# How to configure Progress Bar and Progress Indicator of javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I am trying to add a slider on my page like progress bar. But my code is not working well.

My task is when I am going to copy something from one location to another I want to display a progress bar on my page.
So in javaFx I wrote following task but it is not working well. That code runs but I want show the work in percentage like 30%, 50% and "finish". But my code fails to gives me like requirement so please help me.

My code is:

1.Declaration of progress bar and progress indicator

```
@FXML
final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
@FXML
final ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
```

2.Assign values when I click on copy button.

```
@FXML
private void handleOnClickButtonAction(MouseEvent event) {
    if (fromLabel.getText().isEmpty()
            || toLabel.getText().isEmpty()
            || fromLabel.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("No Directory Selected")
            || toLabel.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("No Directory Selected")) {
        // Nothing
    } else {
        progressBar.setProgress(0.1f);
        progressIndicator.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress());
        this.directoryCount.setText("Please Wait !!!");
    }
}
```

This code shows me only 10% completion an then directly shows "done", but I want whole process in percentage like 10,20,30,.. etc and then "done".

---

My copy code:

```
double i = 1;
while (rst.next()) {
    File srcDirFile = new File(fromLabel.getText() + "/" + rst.getString("nugget_media_files"));
    File dstDirFile = new File(toLabel.getText() + "/" + rst.getString("nugget_media_files"));
    File dstDir = new File(toLabel.getText() + "/" + rst.getString("nugget_directory"));
    if (srcDirFile.lastModified() > dstDirFile.lastModified()
            || srcDirFile.length() != dstDirFile.length()) {
        copyDirectory(srcDirFile, dstDirFile, dstDir);
    }

    this.currentNuggetCount = i / this.nuggetFolderSize;

    System.out.println("Nugget Count : " + this.currentNuggetCount);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setProgress(1.0f);
            progressIndicator.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress());
        }
    });

    ++i;
}
```

This is the `copyDirectory` method:

```
private static void copyDirectory(File srcDir, File dstDir,File destNugget) {
    System.out.println(srcDir+" >> "+dstDir);
    if(!destNugget.exists()) {
        destNugget.mkdirs();
    }

    if (srcDir.isDirectory()) {
        if (!dstDir.exists()) {
            dstDir.mkdirs();
        }

        String[] children = srcDir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(srcDir, children[i]),
                          new File(dstDir, children[i]),
                          destNugget);
        }
    } else {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(srcDir);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dstDir);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exceptio "+ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exceptio "+ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should update `ProgressBar` from copying routine. Which code do you use to copy?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It will give you Progress bar with progress indicator which depends on the slider control.

```
public class Main  extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Progress Controls");

        final Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setMin(0);
        slider.setMax(50);

        final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
        final ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                pb.setProgress(new_val.doubleValue()/50);
                pi.setProgress(new_val.doubleValue()/50);
            }
        });

        final HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setSpacing(5);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(slider, pb, pi);
        scene.setRoot(hb);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enter your code inside a Task and set within UpdateProgress method. Before you run the Task you have to set progressBar.progressProperty (). Bind (task.progressProperty ());

This is an example:
[TaskTest](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2774481)